# How to search data in elastic search from JAVA

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elastic search in my project, for searching we have genreally 2 methods:-

- prepareGet
- prepareSearch

What is the difference between the two methods? And, which one is more efficient?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Prepare Search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/0.90/search.html) :

- It allows you to search the documents that match the query you specify in `setQuery()` method. You can also pass `filter` as per your requirement.
- It can be executed across one or more indices and across one or more types.
- When executing a search, it will be broadcasted to all the index/indices shards (round robin between replicas).

[PrepareGet](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/1.7/get.html):

- It is like `findByid()`. You have to specify the id of the document to be fetched.
- Executed for one type under one index.
- The Get operation gets hashed into a specific shard id. It then gets redirected to one of the replicas within that shard id and returns the result.

  `PrepareGet` is more efficient as it fetches the data on the basis of id.

Comment: Thanks for the info :)

Comment: Do u have any skype id to give? Need assistance on elastic search.